# How to get the recently hired employee of each department when two employees of different department have same hiredate?

Tags: sql-server

consider i have the  table Employee

```
fname   lname    dob        hiredate   depid   department    salary

Betty   Kenney  1990-04-29  2005-09-01   4       Sales          20000
George  Sage    1989-03-01  2001-09-01   1       Manufacturing  40000
Aric    Chabott 1980-02-13  2000-09-01   1       Manufacturing  35000
Gregory Thiel   1983-02-14  2003-09-01   1       Manufacturing  25000
Robert  Lomax   1985-04-09  2007-09-01   3       Accounts       15000
Garry   Boling  1981-07-05  2017-09-01   4       Sales          35000
Neistat Jordan  1987-02-14  2017-05-01   2       Programming    45000
Jasmina Aleksic 1985-11-10  2002-09-01   2       Programming    50000
Faith   Harrold 1983-02-14  2017-06-01   1       Manufacturing  40000
Amahl   Dunbar  1993-07-01  2017-07-01   3       Accounts       10000
Neistat Jordan  1987-02-14  2017-05-01   2       Programming    45000
```

now i tried the query to select the most recently hired employee of each department.

```
   select * from employee e where hiredate IN(select max(hiredate) from 
   employee k where e.Depid=k.Depid  
   group by department)
```

but the result i get is

```
fname   lname   dob          hiredate   depid   department      salary

Garry   Boling  1981-07-05  2017-09-01  4       Sales           35000
Neistat Jordan  1987-02-14  2017-05-01  2       Programming     45000
Faith   Harrold 1983-02-14  2017-06-01  1       Manufacturing   40000
Amahl   Dunbar  1993-07-01  2017-07-01  3       Accounts        10000
Neistat Jordan  1987-02-14  2017-05-01  2       Programming     45000
```

notice that i get 2 rows for the job programming. I just need only one record for the job programming(i.e to eliminate the duplicate record)

Comment: The query looks a bit complicated for what it does (you could it with window functions in recent versions of SQL Server) but it is correct. What is the issue?

Comment: If you mean the two identical rows in the result, well, the table has 2 identical rows, too. Which means there is something wrong with the data you put in there and with the table design. Doesn't it have a primary key or a unique constraint?

Comment: I question the value of the report.  What if there is more than one employee hired in the same department on the same day?

Comment: Actually two identical datas were put manually... just bcoz i wanna know how to write the code...(sorry for that).....i just wanted to know how to get max values for identical datas...thats all!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT A.Fname, a.Lname, a.dob, A.hiredate, a.depid, a.department, a.salery
FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY depid ORDER BY hiredate DESC) AS rnm, *
FROM dbo.Employee
) A WHERE A.rnm = 1
```

I use [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) window function. You can use it with PARTITION by  clause, which will add sequential numbers starting from 1 for each of your partitions. The numbers are assigned in the order which you specify with the Order By clause. I put the descending ordering by the hiredate, so within each partition the Employee with the latest hire date will get row_number = 1, the next one will get row_number = 2, etc. . And after that I just filter the rows with row_number = 1